# Permutation of Disjoint Sets of a Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, set-partition

**Problem Description:**

Consider a symmetric group $S_n$ acting on $n$ objects. We partition $S_n$ into two sets $A, B$ such that

1. $A \cap B= \emptyset$ and $A \cup B = S_n$. In other words, $S_n$ is disjoint union of  $A$ and $B$.
2. There exists a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that $A \circ {\pi} =B$. In other words, every product   $a \circ{\pi}$ (where $a \in A$)  is an element $b$ of $B$, and conversely, every $b \in B$ can be written in this way.

**Question:**

For which $n$ we can have $S_n$ that can be partitioned above way?

Edit:

Construction of product can be $\pi \circ A =B$ instead of $A \circ {\pi} =B$. For computational convenience , consider $A \circ {\pi} =B$.

Comment: what is $A^\pi$ the set of permutations of the form $\pi a \pi^{-1}$ i with $a\in A $ ?

Comment: what is $a^{\pi}$ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling , I have edited, please, check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any $n \geq 2$. Partition according to parity so that $A = A_n$ and $B = S_n - A_n$. Take $\pi = (1, 2)$, which is an odd permutation. Since any even permutation in $A$ multiplied by the odd permutation $\pi$ will result in an odd permutation in $B$, we are done.

Comment: @Jim $A$ and $\pi \circ A$ are in bijection, so certainly we need $|A| = \frac{n!}{2} = |B|$. I wouldn't be that surprised if there is some other way to do it, although I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't, either.